# Javascript / Jquery, open a link with a REL tag as if it were clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rel

The designer that I am working with on a project implemented a pop-up so that it is called when a static link is clicked like

`<a href="#" rel="#dialog">Testing Dialog</a>`

Of course, I don't want it as a static link as I have to do things to it before it is shown to the user so I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to make a call with Javascript to do the same thing as if the link above were clicked by the user? Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, with jQuery:

```
$("a[rel='dialog']").click();
```

or:

```
$("a[rel='dialog']").trigger("click");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/fc6Yk/

Comment: I think this is for putting a listener on the static HTML link? I basically don't want to have to use the link at all, rather I need to have my javascript code emulate the functionality as if the user clicked the link (not when they click the link), the goal is that there will be no link on the page for this

Comment: Note: `.trigger` will only work for event handlers that you defined through jQuery.

Comment: @Rick - The above actually simulates a click on the element - no user interaction required.

Comment: I think its on the right track but there is a difference, I believe, as its not reacting the same way (something to do with the #'s in `href="#" rel="#dialog"` maybe?) The designer used some plugin that takes that input exactly and does something with it and I'm sure he has no idea how to do it any other way so I am hoping to figure a way to simulate it exactly (as it does a few things like a pre-styled popup and dims the background) but am a bit confused, it works when I click the regular HTML link as above.. thanks

Comment: @entropo - `.trigger("click")` will still simulate a click on the element, jQuery handler or not. I think you're confusing it with `.triggerHandler()`. I've updated with a demo.

Comment: @karim79: ah, you're right. [.triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) will only handle jQuery-defined event handlers, but `.trigger` will generate an event which bubbles up the DOM tree (for jQuery 1.3+).

Comment: whew ok figured it out, in my case I think its best to do like this: `<a id="testPopupClick" href="#" rel="#dialog">Testing Dialog</a>` and then call it this way: `$("#testPopupClick").trigger("click");`, thanks for the help it put me on the right track

Comment: @Rick: glad you got it working.  Note that this will send a "basic" click event.  (e.g., if you run into a case that depends on some of the [native-click values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent) like `ctrlKey` you won't be able to do that.)

Answer (score 3):

Basic javascript for triggering a click on an element:

```
var clicky = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents"); 
clicky.initEvent("click", true, true); 
targetElement.dispatchEvent(clicky);
```

Docs!

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

For more detailed click events, see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.initMouseEvent

Answer (score 1):

div
for js:

```
function popitup(url) {
        newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    }
```

for html:

```
<div onclick="popitup()"> When you click this, it will pop up</diva>
```